# React hosting on Google cloud bucket No Such Key Error

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, dns, hosting, google-bucket

I am hosting a react website on Google cloud bucket. The bucket is exposed to public internet and cname is pointed to c.storage.googleapis.com. and web settings is also updated to load index.html. Inside bucket there is app.yaml and build folder where index.html is present. 
But when i browse my domain(www.gobillion.co) - which ideally shall load my hosted website. It is instead giving no such key error. What might be the problem here ?

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please include the [redacted] code from your app.yaml file as well as a screenshot or something of your bucket?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serving react app via Google Cloud Storage and loadbalancer, mapping any urls to index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328268/serving-react-app-via-google-cloud-storage-and-loadbalancer-mapping-any-urls-to)

Answer (score 0):

I have a react app and was getting this error

I fixed this by setting in the buckets "Edit Website Configuration"
"Error (404 not found) page" to "index.html"

so when it cant find a path it serves the app page

Comment: Bad for SEO, because the page served with http status 404